# How can I expand a range in a string in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash how can I expand the range in a string var so I can use it in a for loop ?

```
num=9999999X
num=`echo $num | sed 's/X/\{1..9\}/g'`
echo $num #  outputs 9999999{1..9}
echo ${num} #  outputs 9999999{1..9}
echo 9999999{1..9} #outputs 99999991 99999992 99999993 99999994 99999995 99999996 99999997 99999998 99999999
for i in $num
do 
        echo $i

done #  outputs 9999999{1..9}
```

what I want is to loop through the numbers so I can echo one at each line.

Comment: `printf '9999999%d\n' {1..9}`? Not sure what your expected output is. Is `for i in 9999999{1..9}; do echo "$i"; done` not what you want?

Comment: Tthe problem is that the 9999999 is in a var and X can be in other position besides the end of the string. And the range doesn't evaluate inside the string. I mean: `for i in ${num}{1..9}; do echo "$i"; done` works but how I can I set the range if the X is in another arbitrary position ?

Answer (score 1):

Ranges aren't expanded after expanding variables. Use the `seq` command and put the results in an array:

```
num=($(seq ${num/X/1} ${num/X/9}))
for i in "${num[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute `X` with a formatting directive using parameter expansion, then use it together with `printf`; example with `{1..3}`:

```
$ str=9999999X
$ echo "${str/X/%d}"
9999999%d
$ printf "${str/X/%d}\n" {1..3}
99999991
99999992
99999993
```

or with the `X` in the middle of the string:

```
$ str=999X9999
$ echo "${str/X/%d}"
999%d9999
$ printf "${str/X/%d}\n" {1..3}
99919999
99929999
99939999
```